# Setting the inner html text of a < span > element using Zend_Form_Decorators

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I'm trying to set the inner html of the `< span >` tag here , so it looks like:
 Group

this is what i have so far:

```
    $form->addDisplayGroup(
                array(
                        ................
                ),
                'maingroup1',
                array(
                    'legend'=>'',
                    'disableDefaultDecorators'=> true,
                    'decorators'=> array('FormElements',
                                        array('FieldSet',array('class'=>'dashed-outline2')),
                                        array(array('SpanTag' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'span','class' => 'group',)),
                                        array('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'div','id'=>'group1','class'=>'group','openOnly'=> true))
                                        )
                )
            );
```

Is there a setter / property that I can use to set the inner text of the `< span>` element using Zend_form_decorators?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use html? It would take far less code. :)

Comment: Can't you just set the legend attribute to "Group"? That wouldn't put it into the span yet perhaps it's sufficient (?)

Comment: hi nuqqsa
thanks for the suggestion. <legend> can be applied to <fieldset> only. Are you suggesting that I apply the <legend> to the <div>?
I have a number of fieldsets within a parent div, but need the legend to be applied to the <div>.
Currently i did this with javascript (setting the title onload) but on the face of it its a terrible solution. it was that versus not working with zend forms and currently its too late in the dev stage to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to start "hacking" or "figuring out how..." the best way to do something, its usually a hint you may be going down the wrong road. :-/

My best advice - based on how I understand your question - is that you might have to develop your own partial view for this display group.  When you create your displaygroup, you can set your own decorators:

```
decorators' => array(
    array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'path/to/viewscript.phtml')),
),
```

This will allow you the find-grained control you need.  I know, it seems like a headache to have to create that view for your display group, but, IMHO, that is the 'best practice' to modify decorator contents when there is no clear way.